# using where clause after get last record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

```
using (EPOSEntities1 db = new EPOSEntities1())
{
    List<ActionPerformed> PLUlist = db.ActionPerformeds.ToList();
    ActionPerformed Latest_PLU = PLUlist.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This returns the last record stored. However I have now added another column in the table File_Name, how can I add a where clause to this to say orderByDescending to get the latest file, then from there get the first record with the file_Name as 'Sales'.??

so e.g.

```
    File_Name Date
12) Products 11/02/2014
13) Sales    11/02/2014
14) Products 11/02/2014
```

this would return record 13??

Comment: Why are you pulling the entire list into memory in order to filter out the one record instead of doing all of that filtering in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where` clause before `OrderByDescending`, if you call ToList it will cause immediate evaluation of the query and records will populated. It will be better if you call Where before evaluation.

```
ActionPerformed Latest_PLU = db.ActionPerformeds.Where(c=>File_Name == "Sales")
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just a usual troll. I got the same thing, and it really bothers me.

Answer (score 2):

The `Where` method can filter your collection to only those items where the `File_Name` is `"Sales"`.

Consider placing your LINQ query before the executing call so that your LINQ-to-DB provider can perform the query server-side and only return you one item. What you were doing is bringing the entire `ActionPeformeds` table down from the server to the client, then performing the query client-side.

```
ActionPerformed Latest_PLU = db.ActionPerformeds
    .Where(x => x.File_Name == "Sales")
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

By "executing call" I mean `ToList()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc.

Comment: There, untrolled, +1 for looking an inch deeper than the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionPerformed Latest_PLU = PLUlist.Where(p => p.File_Name == 'Sales').OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```